# How to share directories between git branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

How can I share one or more folders from one or more branches of a git repository?

Answer (score 2):

Another potential option:

If you have branch A (which has folders v, w, and x) and branch B (with folders x, y, and z) and you want folder x to always be the same, then this may be a situation where you want folder x to be in a different branch. Then both branch A and B can merge with X.

Answer (score 1):

Within one Git repo, you don't have to do anything to share a directory between branches: simply don't mark it for removal (`git rm`), and when you create or checkout a branch, that directory will still be there.